# Display data of objects in table in ascending order angularjs

Tags: angularjs

When I console.log my `details` variable I get the following results:

`details:{
          111:{
             2015-2-10 : 0
             2015-2-11 : 0
             2015-2-12 : 0
             2015-2-13 : 0
             2015-2-14 : 0
             2015-2-15 : 0
             2015-2-16 : 0
             2015-2-17 : 0
             2015-2-18 : 0
             2015-2-19 : 0
             2015-2-2  : 0
             2015-2-20 : 0
             2015-2-21 : 0
             2015-2-22 : 0
             2015-2-23 : 0
             2015-2-24 : 0
             2015-2-25 : 0 
             2015-2-26 : 0
             2015-2-27 : 1
             2015-2-28 : 1
             2015-2-3  : 0
             2015-2-4  : 0
             2015-2-5  : 0
             2015-2-6  : 0
             2015-2-7  : 0
             2015-2-8  : 0
             2015-2-9  : 0
             2015-3-1  : 0
          }
 }`

Now I want them to convert in table and achieve the output which looks like this:

The dates are inline and in ascending order but I am not sure how to that. Am I doing right or should I re-code it?

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>no</td>
    <td>2015-2-10</td>
    <td>2015-2-11</td>
    <td>2015-2-12</td>
    <td>2015-2-13</td>
    <td>2015-2-14</td>
    <td>2015-2-15</td>
    <td>2015-2-16</td>
    <td>2015-2-17</td>
    <td>2015-2-18</td>
    <td>2015-2-19</td>
    <td>2015-2-20</td>
    <td>2015-2-21</td>
    <td>2015-2-22</td>
    <td>2015-2-23</td>
    <td>2015-2-24</td>
    <td>2015-2-25</td>
    <td>2015-2-26</td>
    <td>2015-2-27</td>
    <td>2015-2-28</td>
    <td>2015-3-1</td>
    <td>2015-3-2</td>
    <td>2015-3-3</td>
    <td>2015-3-4</td>
    <td>2015-3-5</td>
    <td>2015-3-6</td>
    <td>2015-3-7</td>
    <td>2015-3-8</td>
    <td>2015-3-9</td>
    <td>2015-3-10</td>
    <td>2015-3-11</td>
    <td>2015-3-12</td>
    <td>2015-3-13</td>
    <td>2015-3-14</td>
    <td>2015-3-14</td>
    <td>2015-3-15</td>
    <td>2015-3-16</td>
    <td>2015-3-17</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>111
      <td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>222
      <td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

My working plunker is http://plnkr.co/edit/dQO3D1Omc0o7ZH9TfeUZ?p=preview.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am confused by your question. Are you trying to display your data in a table? You could do a similar thing that your doing in your plunker, using ng-repeat to display a first row which is the key and the second row containing the value.

Comment: Yes I am trying to display my data in the table. But when I display them in the table, the dates are not in ascending order as you noticed. The date is start at `2015-2-11` and end at `2015-3-9` which is wrong. It should end at `2015-2-17`.

Answer (score 1):

Angular provides the [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) filter that you can use to sort things in ng-repeat.

Something like this should work for your details example. I'm not sure what your data values represent or if they're important. You should replicate the following for each data set that you want to order.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="(date, number) in details.111 | orderBy:'date'">
</table>
```

Alternatively, you could store your dates in an array and sort once in the controller.

Comment: What if I want to sort the keys? is it possible?

Comment: Sort by the keys of the `details` object?

Comment: Yes I want to use `orderBy` to sort dates in ascending order. My keys are also dates as you can see in my question.